# How do I determine a Audio file's format when the file name doesn't include a mime type extension in Android?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-audiorecord, android-mediascanner

I have a extension-less file, named for the sake of this post `MyAudioFile`, I know that this audio file's extension is `aac` format(I have analysed it with a program named [`GSpot`](http://gspot.software.informer.com/)), but since the file doesn't have any extension, I am unable to use any of the methods available in Android for determining `MIME` type of that file.

Is there any inbuilt utility method in `Android` that I am unaware of and which lets me read the header information of an audio file and spit out the extension or the `MIME` type of the file?

I have already tried `MediaMetaDataRetriever` and `MimeTypeMap` unsuccessfully, did I miss any other class which can be used here?

Is it possible using any other external libraries excluding `SOX` and `FFMPeg`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand what the problem is here. `MediaMetaDataRetriever` **is** the class to use to determine the metadata (including MIME type) of an arbitrary media file. Are you perhaps using it wrong?

```
MediaMetaDataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetaDataRetriever();
retriever.setDataSource("file:///sdcard/fileThatIsAACButDoesntHaveExtension");
String mimeType = retriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetaDataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_MIMETYPE);
```

How exactly are you trying to use this file? You shouldn't need its MIME type to use it (and you admittedly already *know* its MIME type - `audio/mp4`)

Comment: I used the above it returns null, you see I have some special cases where there are audio files with supposedly no extensions, my goal is to find out the extension of such files programatically and append it to the filename.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you just add the extension manually?

Comment: How do I know the extension beforehand? As I said I analysed the audio file in the above scenario but there are many other audio files, I want to know the mime type of the programatically.

Comment: Ok, i didn't knew that there were many other files. If I have understood you correctly you want to add the extension to a lot of files. Now i don't know GSpot but you use a macro or something like that to automate the process and left the computer over the night?